# Why does my query generate an "undefined name" error with SQLCODE -204?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

This is a SQL Server query

```
select Letter, COUNT(*)
from #Letters
LEFT JOIN Emp ON Name LIKE Letter + '%'
group by Letter
```

but it would not run in DB2, giving an error message:

> "MOHIT.#LETTERS" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704,
>   DRIVER=4.18.60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not table with #LETTERS into your database and into MOHIT Library.
May be into a other Library?

Note: #Tablename are for temporary table in SQL Server, in DB2 its just a table

Note 2: '+' are not an operator of concatenation in DB2, use '||'

your query should be

```
select Letter, COUNT(*)
from #Letters
LEFT JOIN Emp ON Name LIKE Letter || '%'
group by Letter
```

Of course your table shoud be exist in list of Library loaded

Comment: i know + operator is not in db2, but i wnt to know exact query that function is similar