# Why is my query failing with SQLCODE=-204?

Tags: db2, jasper-reports

I'm writing some SQL for a report (this is my first time actually writing SQL so don't slam my syntax too much, lol) and the subquery seems to be failing. I'm not sure why because the report compiles just fine and I can get it into Jaspersoft Studio before it errors out when trying to preview it. Am I even doing the subquery correctly?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
    PERSON.LAST_NAME,
    ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
    SHARE_ESCROW.ID,
    LOAN.PAYMENT_DUE_DATE, 
    LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS.CUSHION_AMOUNT, 
    LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS.NEXT_P_AND_I_AMOUNT,
    LOAN.IMPOUND_AMOUNT,
    LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS.NEXT_IMPOUND_AMOUNT,
    SHARE_ESCROW.BALANCE, 
    SHARE_ESCROW.DESCRIPTION, 
    SHARE_ESCROW.CLOSE_DATE,
    i.LTV,
    CASE LOAN.PAYMENT_METHOD
        WHEN 'T' THEN 'Automated Transfer'
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'ACH'
        WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cash'
    END AS PAYMENT_METHOD
FROM    
    CORE.ACCOUNT AS ACCOUNT INNER JOIN CORE.LOAN AS LOAN ON ACCOUNT.SERIAL = LOAN.PARENT_SERIAL INNER JOIN
    CORE.LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS AS LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS ON LOAN.SERIAL = LN_IMPOUND_ANALYSIS.PARENT_SERIAL INNER JOIN
    CORE.SHARE AS SHARE_ESCROW ON ACCOUNT.SERIAL = SHARE_ESCROW.PARENT_SERIAL INNER JOIN
    CORE.PERSON AS PERSON ON PERSON.SERIAL = ACCOUNT.PRIMARY_PERSON_SERIAL,
    (SELECT 
        CASE COLLATERAL.AMOUNT
            WHEN 0 THEN 0
            WHEN NULL THEN 0
            ELSE LOAN.BALANCE / COLLATERAL.AMOUNT
        END AS LTV

    FROM
        CORE.COLLATERAL AS COLLATERAL INNER JOIN LOAN ON LOAN.SERIAL = COLLATERAL.PARENT_SERIAL
    ) i
WHERE
    SHARE_ESCROW.DESCRIPTION = 'Escrow Share' AND 
    SHARE_ESCROW.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND
    i.LTV != 0
```

Edit: 
Here's the error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Escrow32Analysis324532WIP_TableDataset_1579697577915_289752
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:466)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$18(ReportControler.java:441)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Escrow32Analysis324532WIP_TableDataset_1579697577915_289752
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:809)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTableSubreport.prepareSubreport(FillTableSubreport.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.prepare(FillTable.java:400)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:332)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:384)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1065)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:329)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:159)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Escrow32Analysis324532WIP_TableDataset_1579697577915_289752
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:240)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:691)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1314)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:931)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:873)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:665)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=CMURPHY.LOAN, DRIVER=4.13.127
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:677)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.no.c(no.java:2653)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.no.d(no.java:2641)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.no.a(no.java:2090)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:7671)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.h(cb.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.b(cb.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.i(sb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.no.ib(no.java:2059)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.sc(oo.java:3559)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.b(oo.java:4348)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.fc(oo.java:743)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.executeQuery(oo.java:713)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:233)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: For the line `CORE.COLLATERAL AS COLLATERAL INNER JOIN LOAN ON LOAN.SERIAL`   try replacing with `CORE.COLLATERAL AS COLLATERAL INNER JOIN CORE.LOAN AS LOAN  ON LOAN.SERIAL `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my query generate an "undefined name" error with SQLCODE -204?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174586/why-does-my-query-generate-an-undefined-name-error-with-sqlcode-204)

Comment: You can use a SQL editor that has in-built local Db2 syntax parsing, this can help spot errors such as this. Look at IBM Data Studio  or IBM DB2 Database Management Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you see in the log:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=CMURPHY.LOAN
```

means that the object (in your case a table) `LOAN` in the schema `CMURPHY` cannot be found (SQLCODE -204). As others have mentioned in comments, the only table reference in your query that is missing the explicit schema is this:

```
FROM 
    CORE.COLLATERAL AS COLLATERAL INNER JOIN LOAN ON LOAN.SERIAL ...
---------------------------------------------^^^^
```

so the database server by default looks for that table in the default schema, the one matching your user ID (CMURPHY). Apparently it's not there.

Add the explicit schema name to the table reference:

```
FROM 
    CORE.COLLATERAL AS COLLATERAL INNER JOIN CORE.LOAN AS LOAN ON LOAN.SERIAL ...
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. It seems to be working now.